# How to check if one value of an object is null

Tags: c#, object, isnullorempty

I have an object with multiple strings.
Is there a way to check if one of the values is null or all values are set?
Or do I have to do it like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(object.string1) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(object.string2) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(object.string3))
{

}
```

Comment: Well, if you have only 3 properties you can keep this, else you may get help from reflection.

Comment: Is the object's state invalid if one of them is not set? _Should_ all three be set at all times of the lifetime of that object? Are the strings (fields) mutable?

Comment: @Fildor the fields are mutable. I create an empty object and before I want to add this object to a list, I want to make sure, that all required fields have values

Comment: Your condition will be `true` if any one of the items is non-null/whitespace, even if one or more is null/whitespace. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gather all your strings into an array and then run `.Any()` method:

```
if (new[] { obj.string1, obj.string2, obj.string3 }.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace))
{
    
}
```

Alternatively you can use reflection (which will affect your code's performance), to scan all the strings of your object and check your condition:

```
var anyEmpty = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Any(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)
              && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.GetValue(obj) as string));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate trough all strings and check if they are blank or empty.

EDIT: You probably have to add all the strings into an array or a list, because they all have different names like string1, string2 and string3

Answer (score 1):

If you do this a lot, you could write a method to check it:

```
public static class Ensure
{
    public static bool NoneNullOrWhitespace(params string?[] items)
    {
        return !items.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
    }
}
```

Which for your case you would call like this:

```
if (Ensure.NoneNullOrWhitespace(object.string1, object.string2, object.string3))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option for you to define a class for your objects, you could let the class itself handle the "all strings not null or whitespace"-check:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }
    public string String3 { get; set; }

    public bool StringsAreNotNullOrWhiteSpace => !Strings.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);

    private string[] Strings => new[] { String1, String2, String3 };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
//Populate myObject

if (myObject.StringsAreNotNullOrWhiteSpace)
{
    //Add myObject to list
}
```

(The implementation of `StringsAreNotNullOrWhiteSpace` is basically what @mickl did in their first suggestion, but returning the opposite bool value.)